# os.listdir(path) is adding extra backward slash in filepath

Tags: python, string, path, listdir

the command os.listdir(path) is adding an extra backward slash along all my filepath.
Below the code.

```
import os
import glob
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader

mergedObject = PdfFileMerger()
rootdir = "C:\\Users\\Data\\2021\\02\\"
print ("Rootdir=" + rootdir)
thing = "TodosPDFs.pdf"

# Loop through all of subfolders and then pdf's and append their pages
for sub in os.listdir(rootdir):
    path = rootdir+sub 
    print ("Path = "+ path)
    arr = os.listdir(path)
    if thing in arr: os.remove(path+thing)
    mergedObject = PdfFileMerger()
    for filepath in glob.iglob(path+"*.pdf"):
       print(filepath)
       mergedObject.append(PdfFileReader(filepath, 'rb'))
    mergedObject.write(path+"TodosPDFs.pdf")
    mergedObject.close()
    print("PDF Created")
```

**Expected result is to merge all pdf's included in the subfolders.**

**Error Message:**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\leona\OneDrive - PRODESP\Scripts\Python\MergePdf_multipleSubfolders.py", line 16, in 
arr = os.listdir(path)
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid:
'C:\Users\Data\2021\02\28MQ0221.txt'

**I have tried:**
-I have added print along the script to show that transformation is occuring in 'os.listdir'.

-The code was running ok, I tried to manually add an if the rootdir[-1] != "//" then add a "//" to correct the string. It didnt't worked well, then I returned to the old code backed up scipt but it wasn't working anymore.

I am using windows and VsCode as IDE.

Answer (score 0):

```
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\Users\Data\2021\02\28MQ0221.txt'
```

You feed path to *.txt file to `os.listdir`, which caused this error. Before feeding argument you should check if it is actually directory, for example using `os.path.isdir` function.

Comment: Your solution worked. 
I didn't noticed that the problem was generated by the files in the main directory. thank you!